# Creating an unordered list whose list items control which image will be displayed

Tags: jquery, css

Hi everyone I am pretty much trying to recreate the fuctionality of the map shown here:
http://bike.sombriocartel.com/shopsplash/.

Unfortunately I am stuck on how to build the functionality of switching the image when hovering over its respective list item.

PS. Explanation on the classes and build of the html:

The default class will be the image shown in the world map container (image-container) while I have set the rest (europe-hover, america-hover etc.) in display: hidden and I want each of them to be displayed on top of the default image when the mouse pointer is hovered over their respective list item.

ie. When hovering over "Europe" the image with europe highlighted (europe-hover) on the world map will be shown in place of the default image.

```
<div class="world-map">
 <ul class="region-list">
  <li>Europe<li> 
  <li>America</li>
  <li>Africa</li>
  <li>Asia</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="image-container">
  <img class="default" src='images/map/default-world-map.png'>
  <img class="europe-hover" src='images/h-europe.png'>
  <img class="america-hover" src='images/h-america.png'>
  <img class="africa-hover" src='images/h-africa.png'>
  <img class="asia-hover" src='images/h-asia.png'>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tips for "recreating" sites: read their source code and learn from it. This question is too broad and you've given us no code to help you with

Comment: Thank you taking the time to reply and sorry if my question is too general. I am not trying to recreate their site just the map feature you can see in the link. I will work on it some more and add my code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simpel:

Make shure that the `hover` maps are on top of the default map (play around with positoning) and set their opacity to 0;

```
overlay{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I added some extra classes to easely access the maps with jQuery:

```
<div class="world-map">
 <ul class="region-list">
  <li class="europe">Europe<li> 
  <li class="america">America</li>
  <li class="africa">Africa</li>
  <li class="asia">Asia</li>
 </ul>
 <div class="image-container">
  <img class="default" src='images/map/default-world-map.png'>
  <img class="overlay europe" src='images/h-europe.png'>
  <img class="overlay america" src='images/h-america.png'>
  <img class="overlay africa" src='images/h-africa.png'>
  <img class="overlay asia" src='images/h-asia.png'>
 </div>
</div>
```

Then you can do something like:

```
$('.region-list li').hover(
    function () {
       $('.image-container')
       .find('.' + $(this).attr('class'))
       .animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
    },
    function () {
        $('.image-container')
       .find('.' + $(this).attr('class'))
       .animate({opacity: 0}, 200);
 });
```

What im doing here? When hovering the "name - listitems" im searching for li items with a similar class name and animate their opacitiy to 1. When loosing the focus it automatically animates the opacity back to 0.

This code is not tested it should you give an idea of how to achieve somthing like this.

Comment: Thank you Steven I have a better idea on how to make it work now!

Comment: Of course there a hundrets of ways to do this :) you are welcome :)